# Core Data - updates to persistent store not working

Tags: iphone, core-data

This has been driving me crazy trying to figure this out...

I have a managed object where I need to set an attribute to flag the record is a favorite

The problem is that I don't see the value saved to the database (I have pulled the database from the simulator and inspected it???)

The following is the code snippet ... Note no error is thrown from the save

```
// Tell the user we have added to favorites

NSString *yes = @"Y";

[cardMessage setValue:yes forKey:@"favorite"];

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL savedSuccessfully = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
if (!savedSuccessfully)
{
     /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. 
         You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it 
         may be useful during development. 
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
       message:@"Message added to Favorites" delegate:self 
       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite Manager (Browser Plug) to view the data from the Simulator db - fast and easy (Firefox plug).
https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/
Use - (BOOL)hasChanges - in case something unexpected went wrong (no change for example).

Comment: I am already using Firefox plugin to view the data... hence the confusion as to why the updates are not reflected

Comment: I added the following to log if changes have occurred ... NSLog(@"Before Save... Changes = %@\n", ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] ? @"YES" : @"NO")); - The result was NO !!! ... Which was after the updates were made to the managed object ... I think I might be getting closer... Thanks

Comment: This is still driving me crazy... something basic is wrong.... I have now written some logic to re-read the record and then update a parameter... all the code works but does not save the data to the database... the following is the code

Comment: FIXED YIPPEE ... Commented out the following line in the fetch request

[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];